# Adding an empty row to an Snowpark DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using Snowpark Python, how do I add an empty row full of null values for each column to my table in Snowflake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return your original (main) DataFrame together with a single null-values row:

```
# Main DataFrame
df = session.table("employees")

# Create empty row DF
emptyRow = dict((c, None) for c in df.columns)
emptyRowDf = session.create_dataframe([emptyRow])

unionDf = emptyRowDf.union_all(df)
unionDf.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code also worked for me

```py
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.types import *
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    mytable = session.table(""test1"")
  session.create_dataframe([[None]*len(mytable.columns)],schema=mytable.schema).write.mode("append").save_as_table("test1")
    return session.table("test1")
```